# Add "arrow direction" on GPX trace

Tags: openlayers-3, gpx

I searched without success how to add some "arrow direction" on a GPX trace.
I used this code to display a trace :

```
var center = ol.proj.transform([4.90756, 45.5172], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()})],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({attributionOptions:  ({ collapsible: false})}),
  view: new ol.View({center: center,zoom: 12})
});

var vectorGpx = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'http://www.vlsm.fr/test/test1.gpx',
    format: new ol.format.GPX()
  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#1aa79b',width: 3})})
});
map.addLayer(vectorGpx);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bzyev869/

Does something exist to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openlayers 3 doesnt have inbuilt functionality to add arrow-style.However,you can calculate direction between lat long and add arrow icon.Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bzyev869/2/

```
  for(var i=0;i<vectorGpx.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0].length;i++){
     var s= vectorGpx.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0][i];
      if(i+1 <vectorGpx.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0].length){
      var f= vectorGpx.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0][i+1];
      }
          var dx = s[0] - f[0];
        var dy = s[1] - f[1];

      var rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

         styles.push(new ol.style.Style({
          geometry: new ol.geom.Point([f[0],f[1]]),
          image: new ol.style.Icon({
            src: 'http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/data/arrow.png',
            anchor: [0.75, 0.5],
            rotateWithView: false,
            rotation: -rotation
          })
        }));               
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I modified a little the code to obtain an arrow every km and change this distance regarding the zoom map level. http://jsfiddle.net/bzyev869/6/. It's a little pity that the distance between each arrow will be not compulsory the same due tho the distance between each points in the GPS file.

Comment: thanks :) Please don't forget to upvote this answer if it is useful to you,Thanks!